# Learn the value in the table not by ID number

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a table:

- 5000
- 4900
- 4800
- 4700
- 3800
- 3600
- 2000
- 1900
- 1600
- 1000

The table does not have identification numbers.
The table is sorted by the decay, the greatest value from above.Question. How to make a mysql query to find a value of 5 on the list item? The column ID, no ...
Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the column name? Does the table have any other columns?

Comment: A *table* is *never* sorted. It must be considered as an *unordered set* of rows. Query result set *might* be sorted if *explicitly* requested (`ORDER BY`).

Answer (score 3):

I am going to interpret this as finding the fifth value in the list.  You can do this using `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by col desc
limit 4, 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to find a row which had value 5?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ID = 5
```

or if you mean you want the fifth element in the list,

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
LIMIT 5,1
```